# uglifyjs command for content getting error

Tags: msbuild, uglifyjs

I am trying to use uglifyjs to minify and create a sourcemap when running msbuild.  I'm getting an error, so I've cut MSBuild out of the loop and run it from the command line, but am still getting an error if I include content:

This works from the command line, creating the appropriate min file:

```
node_modules\.bin\uglifyjs.cmd wwwroot\lib\jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js 
   --source-map "url='jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js.map',includeSources" 
   -o wwwroot\lib\jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js -c -m
```

But this (which is basically the example I got from another project) throws an error

```
node_modules\.bin\uglifyjs.cmd wwwroot\lib\jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js 
   --source-map "url='jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js.map',content='wwwroot/lib/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js.map',includeSources" 
   -o wwwroot\lib\jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js -c -m
```

```
ERROR: invalid input source map: wwwroot/lib/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js.map
    at parse_source_map (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\xxx\source\temp\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:18:1), <anonymous>:22118:15)
    at Object.minify (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\xxx\source\temp\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:18:1), <anonymous>:22234:38)
    at run (C:\Users\xxx\source\temp\node_modules\uglify-js\bin\uglifyjs:379:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxx\source\temp\node_modules\uglify-js\bin\uglifyjs:287:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

What am

Comment: Looks like --output might help get the sourcemap created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is exactly as it states...

> invalid input source map

`--source-map` has various options, in the example throwing the error you have

`content='wwwroot/lib/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js.map'`

This is called a composed source map

> When you're compressing JS code that was output by a compiler such as
> CoffeeScript, mapping to the JS code won't be too helpful. Instead,
> you'd like to map back to the original code (i.e. CoffeeScript).
> UglifyJS has an option to take an input source map. Assuming you have
> a mapping from CoffeeScript → compiled JS, UglifyJS can generate a map
> from CoffeeScript → compressed JS by mapping every token in the
> compiled JS to its original location.
>
> To use this feature pass --source-map
> "content='/path/to/input/source.map'" or --source-map "content=inline"
> if the source map is included inline with the sources.

see https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS#composed-source-map

However that file `wwwroot/lib/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js.map` is not well formed. You can see the error is thrown at `parse_source_map`

If you take a look at that method you can see that all it is doing is attempting to parse the content as the JavaScript value. e.g.

```
function parse_source_map(content) {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(content); // <- this is what is failing
    } catch (ex) {
        // ... and this is the error you are seeing
        throw new Error("invalid input source map: " + content);
    }
}
```

To fix, ensure that the file `wwwroot/lib/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js.map` is acceptable to `JSON.parse` or else remove the `content` option as it seems to be redundant in your case.

Comment: Would the problem be that the the original code in this case is js?

Comment: No, the problem is that whatever is in that file is not parsable to a JavaScript object. That is what `JSON.parse` does - turns a string into valid JS or throws an error.

Comment: I’m trying to get it to create the source app…anyway, meant to award bounty but missed the deadline, trying again with a new bounty.